# How to get count value assign the table

Tags: java, android

I get some number from URL, if the number is b/w 1 to 4 then I want's the result to be 4, .. and number b/w 4 to 8 then I want result 8 ......And so on.

This is my code. and this is get from url in count value.

```
adltavailable = Integer.parseInt(count.get(i).toString());

for(int x =0; x<adltavailable; x++)
{
    c = "Adultavailable";
    category.add(c);
}
```

//Here is assign the table

```
int k = 0;
int size = category.size();
while(k < size)
{   
    for(int z=0; z<size; z++)
    {                                   
        if(category.get(z).equals("Adultavailable"))
        {
            mycirimgs[k].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultadd);
        }
        k++;    
    }
}
```

I get total seats value from url .And the value is assigned in table.If suppose i got 3 seats means I assign the table in 3 seats is not look like good.But this three seats assign 4 instead of 3.like wise.So I want the result If I get total seats 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 means I assign the table in 4 seats and 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 means I assign the table in 8 seats like wise. Thanks giving ur support.

Comment: What do you use `mycirimgs` for?

Comment: this is assign background image

Comment: So you have 8 View objects and you want either 4 or 8 of them to have a background image indicating a seat in a table of 4 or 8?

Comment: hey try my answer i hope get success..

Answer (score 1):

> I get some number from URL, if the number is b/w 1 to 4 then I want's the result to be 4, .. and number b/w 4 to 8 then I want result 8 ......And so on.

To round `x` to the next multiple of 4, write

```
(x + 3) & ~3
```

where `+ 3` rounds up and `& ~3` clears the bottom two bits making it a multiple of 4.

Comment: firstly you are the one answered.But user `Ramani` copied and posted your answer.Then that answer was accepted within one minutes.I think questions and answer posted by same user.

Comment: @Stephen You can raise a custom moderator flag when you see such things happening.

Comment: yes just before I flag it to moderator.I believe moderator will take care about these.

Answer (score 0):

To round up your input to the next multiple of 4, you can try the following:

```
Integer result;
if (input % 4 == 0) //Input is already a multiple of 4.
{
  result = input
}
else // round up
{
  result = ((input / 4) + 1)*4
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.